# Limit CPU usage when creating containers using the Docker API

Tags: api, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a container using the Docker API with a limit on CPU usage. I was able to find documentation regarding the `--cpus=<value>` option that you can pass when using Docker on the command line, but I'm not sure if this feature is available using the HTTP API.

Is there a way to pass this option using the HTTP API, or is there a comparable alternative for limiting CPU usage of a container? There are options that are documented for the API like `CPUCount` and `CPUPercent` that are marked "Windows Only", but I'm running Docker on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but if someone is still looking for this, in the HTTP API you have access to: CpuQuota and CpuPeriod which you can use to limit the CPU.

For example if you have only one CPU and want to limit the usage to 50% you can do it with the following options:

```
"HostConfig": {
  "CpuPeriod": 100000,
  "CpuQuota": 50000,
}
```